# Missing after argument on getting select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, arguments

I write some code for a project. Now I can't find what is wrong.

This is my code:

```
$('#zielland').replaceWith('<select id="zielland" name="destination_country">"{herkunfstland}"</select>');
```

{herkunfstland} output following:

```
('<select id="zielland" name="destination_country">;
<option value="AFG" data-id="">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="DZA" data-id="">Algeria</option>
<option value="ASM" data-id="">American Samoa</option>
<option value="AGO" data-id="">Angola</option>
<option value="AIA" data-id="">Anguilla</option>
<option value="ATG" data-id="">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="ARG" data-id="">Argentina</option>
<option value="ARM" data-id="">Armenia</option>
<option value="ABW" data-id="">Aruba</option>
<option value="AUS" data-id="">Australia</option>
<option value="AZE" data-id="">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="BHS" data-id="">Bahamas</option>
<option value="BHR" data-id="">Bahrain</option>
<option value="BGD" data-id="">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="BRB" data-id="">Barbados</option>
<option value="BLZ" data-id="">Belize</option>
<option value="BEN" data-id="">Benin</option>
"</select>');
```

I hope that somebody can help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Remove the double quotes around `{herkunfstland}`

Comment: can you please format the 2nd code box, so ppl can read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your first code block with

```
$('#zielland').replaceWith(`<select id=zielland name=destination_country>${herkunfstland}</select>`);
```

In order for you to use the `${ }` syntax you must place it inside backticks.